# Strange behavior with addition of a std::vector declaration?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have encountered a strange and inconsistent behavior from the following program:

**CAUTION: THE PROGRAM BELOW HAS POSSIBLY UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR AND MAY HAVE DESTRUCTIVE EFFECTS. RUN IT AT YOUR OWN DISCRETION AND RISK**

Here is a **struct**:

```
struct MyStruct {
    int* myarr;
    int size;

    MyStruct(int size) {
        myarr = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            myarr[i] = i;
        }
    }

    
    
    MyStruct(const MyStruct& other) {
        size = other.size;
        myarr = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            myarr[i] = other.myarr[i];
        }
    }
    

   
    MyStruct(MyStruct&& other) {
        this->myarr = other.myarr;
        this->size = other.size;

        other.myarr = nullptr;
    }

    
    MyStruct& operator=(MyStruct&& other) {
        this->myarr = other.myarr;
        this->size = other.size;

        other.myarr = nullptr;
        return *this;
    }
    
};
```

A function:

```
MyStruct newStruct(MyStruct& temp, int size) { 
    temp = MyStruct{size};
    return temp;
}
```

And the main function:

```
int main() {
    vector<int> myvector {1};
    
    MyStruct tempStruct {2};
    MyStruct myst {newStruct(tempStruct, 5)};
}
```

When I compile this code and run it, the output is either:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_array_new_length'
  what():  std::bad_array_new_length
```

Or it keeps running indefinitely, which after a while I have to kill the process with SIGKILL, as otherwise systems gives me:
'the 'filesystem root has less than X of space left'

The thing is, when I remove either seemingly irrelevant vector declaration, or everything in the main function except vector declaration the problem is solved and the output is exactly as expected.

Replacing the vector declaration with other types such as std::string results in the same behavior.

What's happening?

Comment: You never implemented the copy assignment operator that you use in `temp = MyStruct{size};`.  The default wont give you the correct behavior.

Comment: In your converting constructor `MyStruct(int size)`, you never initialize the actual member variable `MyStruct::size`. In turn, this means that your copy and move constructors rely on UB by accessing an uninitialized variable.

Comment: You might want to read about the [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: @NathanPierson How did I miss that! Wow, I have been trying to figure out what was happening for hours...Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need `MyStruct` at all?  Why not simply use `std::vector<int>`?

Comment: @AntiClub Personally, my alarms were raised when I noticed that the constructor parameter `size` had the same name as the member variable `size`. I was going to suggest cranking up warning levels, but apparently gcc has a hard time detecting that `MyStruct::size` isn't initialized even if I use it. EDIT: Oh, right, you have to have optimization levels high enough for it to catch this stuff. `-Wall -O2` should catch the uninitialized variable.

Comment: @NathanPierson yes, I actually didn't even look at that specific constructor thinking it was 'correct' and tried to find what is going on by changing other implementations.

Comment: @NathanPierson What is the relation with the vector (or string) declaration though?
I wrote a script which runs the program thousand times but none of them really produced any error. Whereas every execution of program with vector declaration fails.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I was just playing aroung with copy constructors, overloaded operators etc... So it is not for use really.

Comment: `int* myarr;` - But why? Why not just use a `std::array` or `std::vector` ?

Comment: @AntiClub *I wrote a script which runs the program thousand times but none of them really produced any error.* -- `int main() { MyStruct m1(10); MyStruct m2(10); m1 = m2; }` -- that produces a memory leak.  Wrap that up in a `for` loop, and watch your memory usage go up and up.

Comment: @AntiClub Undefined behavior. When you have UB, seemingly innocuous changes can have drastic effects on the observed output.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie
 Well there is no copy assignment in the incorrect version but I have implemented and... Same, no error whatsoever. I have also changed the constructor which prints (this->size) and it is 0 all the time (limited to thousands instances). But as
NathanPierson pointed out, it seems to be a result of chaotic undefined behavior and would change with different implementations/compilers.

Comment: @AntiClub I'd recommend reading https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub and especially all the very good articles linked at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out correctly in the comments, constructor MyStruct(int size) doesn't initialize the member variable MyStruct::size, thus causing an undefined behavior.